# Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ the set $A_\epsilon = \{x \in X | d(x, A) < \epsilon\}$ is an open set in $X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ a metric space and $A \subset X$. Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ the set $A_\epsilon = \{x \in X | d(x, A) < \epsilon\}$ is an open set in $X$

Well I know that what open set means is that $A^0_\epsilon = A_\epsilon$ (also there are other equivalences).

I understand $A_\epsilon$, but I don´t know how to start.

Any suggestions would be grat!

Comment: As a hint: what topology do you want $A_\epsilon$ to be open in? How do we characterize the open sets of the topology induced by a metric?

Comment: $B^d_r(x)$? So I need to determine $r$ and $x$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove $A_\epsilon = \bigcup\limits_{a\in A} B(a,\epsilon)$ where $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the open ball with center $x$ and radius $\epsilon$.

It is easy to see that $A_\epsilon \supseteq \bigcup\limits_{a\in A} B(a,\epsilon)$ because $d(A,x)\leq d(a,x)$

In order to prove the other containment pick a point such that $d(A,x)<\epsilon$, recall what the definition of $d(A,x)$ is, and use infimum properties to conclude there must be an $a\in A$ with $d(a,x)<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5):

Check that the map

$$f: X \to \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto d(x,A)$$

is continuous (in fact, it might be easier to show it is $1$-Lipschitz).

Then $A^\epsilon = f^{-1}((-\infty, \epsilon))$ is open, as inverse image of an open set under a continuous map.